# CSS box-shadow with transparent background and pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-shapes

I have a div that i would like to look like a speech bubble with a box shadow around. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

problem is i cannot figure out how to add the shadow to the psuedo element "tail". Is this even possible? If i add box-shadow to the pseudo element, it looks like this which is certainly not i want:

[image]

I would really appreciate any guidance on this. Thanks

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gyyc9L9/)

Code:

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #Febb68;
  padding: 30px;
}
#bubble {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px 60px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 30px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #944;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}
#bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 85px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='bubble'>
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: This question is different from [CSS Speech Bubble with Box Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866736/css-speech-bubble-with-box-shadow) as the background in this case is transparent( this cannot be changed as the final background is an image and not a solid color) and the pointer slopes on one side only. This is how the solution to that question looks like with transparent background: http://jsfiddle.net/mek5Z/2140/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Speech Bubble with Box Shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866736/css-speech-bubble-with-box-shadow)

Comment: @SalmanA This is not a duplicate of that question. the hack employed by the accepted answer is not applicable to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have successfully got this result, but it needs to be optimized:

`<div id='bubble' class="filter-drop-shadow">`

```
.filter-drop-shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0 10px 1px #944);
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 10px 1px #944);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 10px 1px #944);
    }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gyyc9L9/3/)

Comment: Note that `filter` isn't supported by IE therefore the `-ms-` prefix isn't necessary and the `-o-` prefix never existed for this property (see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters))

Comment: The `-moz-` prefix never existed either. Filters got supported in Firefox unprefixed right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Won't let me comment so had to write this but maybe these references would help.

[CSS Speech Bubble with Box Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866736/css-speech-bubble-with-box-shadow)

and

[How to Create CSS3 Speech Bubbles Without Images](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/)

Comment: @SNAG, yes I see that the first article doesn't work for you. Try the second article there was some good tips on styling psuedo elements.