# How i can make it wiht css3?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

How i can do it with css (box-shadow and border)
How to do it exactly like image.Give me some suggestions please Thanks.

[See image here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GXti.png)

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at the following post for ideas as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866736/css-speech-bubble-with-box-shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your divs css

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 121px -17px rgba(0,106,148,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 121px -17px rgba(0,106,148,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 121px -17px rgba(0,106,148,1);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px -17px rgba(0,179,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px -17px rgba(0,179,255,1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 103px -17px rgba(0,179,255,1);
```

Comment: Also you can find many tools for that.. example : http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow